# Binding in CustomControl

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, custom-controls

I have created a custom control which is (among other things) able to display many expanders in an ItemsControl.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"> <Style TargetType="{x:Type NxTabControl:NxCategoryControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type NxTabControl:NxCategoryControl}">
                   <ScrollViewer x:Name="contentScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                                            <Border>
                                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style> </ResourceDictionary>
```

The ItemsControl is binding to :
ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content} 
Which is a DP in the class:

```
public class CategoryControl : ItemsControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Expander> Content
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Expander>)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(ObservableCollection<Expander>), typeof(CategoryControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ContentCollection(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure)); }
```

I am using my custom control in a user Control by setting the content Property and adding expanders to it:

```
<NxTabControl:NxCategoryControl x:Name="catControl" DockMode="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Green">
   <TabControl:CategoryControl.Content>
         <Expander Margin="0 3 0 3"  IsExpanded="True" Header="Adresse" >
            <ScrollViewer  x:Name="ScrollViewerAdresse" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewerAdresse, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource HalfWidthConverter}}">
                </Grid>
            </ ScrollViewer>
         </Expander>
        <Expander>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header={Binding ExpanderHeader}>
        </Expander>
   </TabControl:CategoryControl.Content>
```

My problem in this context is that I am not able to set this binding:

```
Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewerAdresse, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

And also no other binding that goes to an “ElementName”.  I am e.g also binding to XamDataGrids.ActiveRecords by their name and other Elements. None of the bindings works.

Snoop tells me for the Width Property of the Grid:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ScrollViewerAdresse'. 
BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'Grid'; target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Other bindings  I am using in my expanders, binding to the ViewModel of the usercontrol   work though, e.g.:

```
Header={Binding ExpanderHeader}
```

Any help would be welcome! Thx!

Comment: Is your `ObservableCollection<Expander>` actually holding instances of the [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) Control?  Because this is a complete violation of MVVM and won't work.  You need to hold models in this collection which contain the data that will be represented by the TabControl's templates that will eventually be bound against the Expanders in each template.

Comment: yes, 
<TabControl:CategoryControl.Content> 
contains expanders (extended expanders though), for giving the user of my custom control the possibiliy to put whatever content they want in the control. 
What i basically want to achieve is having something similar to a TabControl, where each tab is in an expander and can be expanded and scrolled to the top by clicking on "select Tab A" ... "select Tab n" Button. This basically works, the only thing that does not is the binding to an element in an expander.

Comment: You skipped over the part where I said "this is a complete violation of MVVM."  Your expanders go into DataTemplates.  You create Models that are exposed in the ObservableCollection that is bound to some ItemsControl type (not sure what is appropriate as I haven't studied your question).  You're doing it wrong from the bottom up.

Comment: Thx Will, not using an ItemsControl and using a StackPanel instead, filled from code behind did the trick. All Bindings work now.

Comment: If you want to use MVVM you should look into it.